# Getting error on executing POST request in Qmetry

Tags: qaf

With Qmetry framework, Trying to execute the below POST request (with xml content in body). Due to client confidentiality, I have not mentioned exact URLs in the below code.

**POST REQUEST**:

```
post.sample.call={'headers':{'SoapAction':'<url here>','Content-Type':'text/xml;charset=UTF-8','Accept':'*/*','Authorization':'<authorization key here>'},'endPoint':'<endpoint here>','baseUrl':'<url here>','method':'POST','query-parameters':{},'form-parameters':{},'body':'<sending xml content here>'}
```

**It throws error** :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed in key must select exactly one node: post.sample.call
```

This works fine when run through postman. But fails with Qmetry.

Any change required in the above post method to run in qmetry? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Error message itself provides the reason!...

> Passed in key must select exactly one node:post.sample.call

Indicates that you may have multiple entries or values of `post.sample.call` property. Issue most probably here is `;` in value. `;` is used as list separator, so if required in property value, add escape char \ before it. For example

```
text/xml\;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Hi user861594, Tried changing with escape char. Now I get error 'is not valid Json'. Does QAF support SOAP api ? The same request works fine with Postman.

Comment: yes, refer [Working-with-SOAP-web-services](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki/Working-with-SOAP-web-services)

Comment: Hi, checked the above link. I am not using any wsdl file here. I triggered soap api  request from Postman & got the response. Generated body xml through code option from postman. Used the same xml in qmetry api call. Copied the xml in body  i.e    'body':' xml copied here'. I get invalid json error. Not sure why am I getting json related error. I am sending xml in the body. Not sure where is the issue.

Comment: Provide request call you are using. It looks syntax error. When you are providing request call you need to make sure that value of property (request call) is valid json. Simplest way is to move request body in separate file and use it. For example: `'body':'file:resources/data/op_req.xml'`. Other way is to provide request call in XML. Refer [example of request call repository](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki/Working-with-SOAP-web-services#example-request-call-repository).

Comment: Hi, Thanks there were special characters in xml body like \r\n. After removing it worked fine. Now to assert xpath in xml response I run this step :  response should have xpath "/soapenv:Envelope" .This throws ERROR :   ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is null, name is null   &   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/jxpath/ri/model/NodePointerFactory .

Comment: you don't need to provide namespace to validate xpath. Also if starting node is not first not use `//` in xpath, for example `//Envelope`

Comment: Tried this one (root node) - And response should have xpath '/Envelope'  . Its returning false. Also tried with //Envelope & didnt work.

Comment: Better you can ask separate question with details.